# Magento 2 update payment method when price is updated on checkout page

Tags: magento2

I want to update the payment methods when product price change greater than zero (0) I am working on a customized project I added the product by default 0 price.

When price is 0 on checkout page payment methods are not shown which is working but when I update price payment methods are not shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the others payment method minimum order total options in your store configuration section of the Admin panel.?